# express.js + reactJs app reload issues

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am developing react and express.js application. Front end is using react router and fro server router its express router. 
In the production, reload is showing `can not Get /exampleRoute/..`.

Here is the `index.js` of `express`.

```
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const logger = require('morgan');
const fs = require('fs');
const port = 8771;
const path= require('path');
const API = require('./api');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use('/index.html',function(req,res){
  res.end();
});

const apiBase = '/api/';
const accounts = require('./routes/accounts');
const auth = require('./routes/auth');

app.use(apiBase + 'accounts', accounts);
app.use(apiBase + 'auth', auth);
app.use(apiBase + 'conversation', conversation);
app.use('/healthcheck', function(req, res) {
  res.json({status: 'UP'});
});
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public')));


console.log(`Server is running on, open http://localhost:${port} to 
 test!`);
server.listen(port);
```

The application is loading normally, but every time refresh is not throwing `404` error. Can anyone suggest me what's wrong with the express server.

Comment: Can you share your front end code?

Comment: This is `index.js` of frontend .                                                                         
`const store = configureStore();
 // Create an enhanced history that syncs navigation events with the store
 const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);
  // Start auth process
  store.dispatch(actions.getAuth());
  window.__myapp_container = document.getElementById('app');
 render(
   <Provider store={store}>
   <Router onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)} history={history} 
         routes={routes} />
    </Provider>, window.__myapp_container
  );`

Comment: Sorry I mean the code calling the route like `/exampleRoute/`

Comment: here is the `react-router` code `<Route path="/" component={requireAuthentication(Layout)}>
    <IndexRoute component={Dashboard}/>
    {AnalysisRoutes}
    {ReportsRoutes}
    <Route path="/workflow" component={Workflow}/>
    <Route path="/error" component={ErrorHandler}/>
    <Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage}/>
  </Route>`